# Empty relation table

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, mariadb

I am doing some exercizes with JDBC/MariaDB trying to implement ER schema
[image]

Bigger image at address:
http://img854.imageshack.us/img854/2513/psfl.jpg

So I started creating Java software

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

import javax.sql.rowset.CachedRowSet;


class DBHandler_test
{  
    private Statement statement = null;
    private Connection connection = null;
    private ResultSet result = null;
    public DBHandler_test()
    {

    }

    public void createTables() throws SQLException, IOException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException
    {
        connection = getConnection();
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        statement.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Possiede");
        statement.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Possiede2");
        statement.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Possiede3");
        statement.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Camera");
        statement.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Oggetto");
        statement.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Parete");
        statement.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Accesso");



        statement.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Camera  (Nome CHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY, Estensione INT, `Livello_1` CHAR(20), `Livello_2` CHAR(20), `Livello_3` CHAR(20), `Livello_4` CHAR(20))");
        statement.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Accesso  (IdA INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Coordinata__X INTEGER, Coordinata__Y INTEGER)");
        statement.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Oggetto (IdO INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Nome CHAR(20), Coordinata_X INTEGER, Coordinata_Y INTEGER)");
        statement.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Parete (IdP INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Coordinata_X CHAR(10), Coordinata_Y CHAR(10))");
        statement.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Possiede (IdO INTEGER NOT NULL, Nome CHAR(20), PRIMARY KEY (IdO), FOREIGN KEY (Nome) REFERENCES Camera(Nome), FOREIGN KEY (IdO) REFERENCES Oggetto(IdO))");
        statement.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Possiede2 (IdA INTEGER NOT NULL, Nome CHAR(20) NOT NULL, Coordinata_X INTEGER, Coordinata_Y INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY (IdA,Nome), FOREIGN KEY (IdA) REFERENCES Accesso(IdA), FOREIGN KEY (Nome) REFERENCES Camera(Nome))");
        statement.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Possiede3 (IdP INTEGER NOT NULL, Nome CHAR(20) NOT NULL,  PRIMARY KEY (IdP, Nome), FOREIGN KEY (Nome) REFERENCES Camera(Nome), FOREIGN KEY (IdP) REFERENCES Parete(IdP))");

        connection.close();
    }

    public void insertRoomsEntries() throws SQLException, IOException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException
    {
        connection = getConnection();
        statement = connection.createStatement();

        statement.execute("INSERT INTO Oggetto(IdO, Nome, Coordinata_X, Coordinata_Y) VALUES (1,'Cappelliera',3,2)");
        statement.execute("INSERT INTO Oggetto(IdO, Nome, Coordinata_X, Coordinata_Y) VALUES (2,'Attaccapanni',6,5)");
        statement.execute("INSERT INTO Oggetto(IdO, Nome, Coordinata_X, Coordinata_Y) VALUES (3,'Letto matrimoniale',3,10)");
        statement.execute("INSERT INTO Oggetto(IdO, Nome, Coordinata_X, Coordinata_Y) VALUES (4,'Comodino',3,9)");
        statement.execute("INSERT INTO Oggetto(IdO, Nome, Coordinata_X, Coordinata_Y) VALUES (5,'Comodino',3,12)");
        statement.execute("INSERT INTO Oggetto(IdO, Nome, Coordinata_X, Coordinata_Y) VALUES (6,'Armadio',7,3)");
        statement.execute("INSERT INTO Oggetto(IdO, Nome, Coordinata_X, Coordinata_Y) VALUES (7,'Bidet',8,2)");
        statement.execute("INSERT INTO Oggetto(IdO, Nome, Coordinata_X, Coordinata_Y) VALUES (8,'Water',10,2)");
        statement.execute("INSERT INTO Oggetto(IdO, Nome, Coordinata_X, Coordinata_Y) VALUES (9,'Lavandino',9,4)");
        statement.execute("INSERT INTO Oggetto(IdO, Nome, Coordinata_X, Coordinata_Y) VALUES (10,'Doccia',12,3)");
        statement.execute("INSERT INTO Oggetto(IdO, Nome, Coordinata_X, Coordinata_Y) VALUES (11,'Televisione',14,4)");
        statement.execute("INSERT INTO Oggetto(IdO, Nome, Coordinata_X, Coordinata_Y) VALUES (12,'Divano',17,5)");
        statement.execute("INSERT INTO Oggetto(IdO, Nome, Coordinata_X, Coordinata_Y) VALUES (13,'Tavolo',20,3)");
        statement.execute("INSERT INTO Oggetto(IdO, Nome, Coordinata_X, Coordinata_Y) VALUES (14,'Frigo',21,8)");
        statement.execute("INSERT INTO Oggetto(IdO, Nome, Coordinata_X, Coordinata_Y) VALUES (15,'Lavello',19,12)");
        statement.execute("INSERT INTO Oggetto(IdO, Nome, Coordinata_X, Coordinata_Y) VALUES (16,'Cestino',16,8)");
        statement.execute("INSERT INTO Oggetto(IdO, Nome, Coordinata_X, Coordinata_Y) VALUES (17,'Letto',8,9)");
        statement.execute("INSERT INTO Oggetto(IdO, Nome, Coordinata_X, Coordinata_Y) VALUES (18,'Comodino',7,8)");
        statement.execute("INSERT INTO Oggetto(IdO, Nome, Coordinata_X, Coordinata_Y) VALUES (19,'Cassettiera',11,8)");


        statement.execute("INSERT INTO Camera VALUES ('Ingresso', 28, 'Ingresso', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL')");
        statement.execute("INSERT INTO Camera VALUES ('Camera da letto 1', 20, 'Ingresso', 'Camera da letto 1', 'NULL', 'NULL')");
        statement.execute("INSERT INTO Camera VALUES ('Bagno', 18, 'Ingresso', 'Corridoio 1', 'Bagno', 'NULL')");
        statement.execute("INSERT INTO Camera VALUES ('Corridoio 1', 20, 'Ingresso', 'Corridoio 1', 'NULL', 'NULL')");
        statement.execute("INSERT INTO Camera VALUES ('Salotto', 48, 'Ingresso', 'Corridoio 1', 'NULL', 'NULL')");
        statement.execute("INSERT INTO Camera VALUES ('Camera da letto 2', 15, 'Ingresso', 'Corridoio 2', 'Camera da letto 2', 'NULL')");
        statement.execute("INSERT INTO Camera VALUES ('Ripostiglio', 12, 'Ingresso', 'Corridoio 2', 'Ripostiglio', 'NULL')");
        statement.execute("INSERT INTO Camera VALUES ('Cucina', 30, 'Ingresso', 'Corridoio 1', 'Salotto', 'Cucina')");

        statement.execute("INSERT INTO Accesso VALUES (1, 6, 5)");
        statement.execute("INSERT INTO Accesso VALUES (2, 6, 7)");
        statement.execute("INSERT INTO Accesso VALUES (3, 11, 4)");
        statement.execute("INSERT INTO Accesso VALUES (4, 13, 5)");
        statement.execute("INSERT INTO Accesso VALUES (5, 18, 7)");
        statement.execute("INSERT INTO Accesso VALUES (6, 6, 12)");
        statement.execute("INSERT INTO Accesso VALUES (7, 10, 11)");
        statement.execute("INSERT INTO Accesso VALUES (8, 14, 12)");

        connection.close();
    }

    public static Connection getConnection()
       throws SQLException, IOException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException
    {  
       Properties props = new Properties();
       FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("/home/caterpillar/workspace/BDC_esercitazione/src/database.properties");
       props.load(in);
       in.close();

       String drivers = props.getProperty("jdbc.drivers");
       if (drivers != null)
          System.setProperty("jdbc.drivers", drivers);
       String url = props.getProperty("jdbc.url");
       String username = props.getProperty("jdbc.username");
       String password = props.getProperty("jdbc.password");
       Class.forName(drivers).newInstance();
       return DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        DBHandler_test dbHandler = new DBHandler_test();
        try
        {
            dbHandler.createTables();
            dbHandler.insertRoomsEntries();
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (InstantiationException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IllegalAccessException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

but when I open Possiede2 table in PHPmyadmin I see that is empty. How is it possible? Camera and Accesso tables are not empty. Did I made any mistakes in SQL commands?

Comment: Did you get any stack-trace?

Comment: I don't see any insert statements that put data into `Possiede2`.  What were you expecting to find there?

Comment: Try using any ORM framework for such complex applications. JDBC days are gone. It would make your life easy.. :)

Comment: @DavidWallace I thought that referencing keys would have let Camera and Accesso to be present in Possiede2 but it seems to not be. Could you please write an answer with an example of INSERT code for Possiede2 ? So I can give you the green mark.

Comment: @AyushyaDevmurari thank you for the suggestion, but I am forced to use JDBC due university course based on SQL.

Comment: Your question indicates that you already know how to write insert statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought that referencing keys would have let Camera and Accesso to be present in Possiede2 but it seems to not be. So I have to manually enter entries, being carefull to choice entries that are in Camera and Accesso tables.
One example of SQL code:

```
INSERT INTO Possiede2 VALUES (6, 'Ingresso', 6, 12)
```